# Are there any modules that can export and import nodes while preserving node id's?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

Our website uses VBO + Views Admin screen for the `admin/people` screen. Today one of the user admins deleted some old user accounts, by checking the checkbox next to the names and selecting the "Delete" option from the Actions dropdown. What he didn't know (+ I didn't know) was that by using the "Delete" option he also inadvertently deleted all the content created by those users as well.

I've got a backup of all the nodes that have been deleted, however I'm at a bit of a loss on what's the best option to restore these. The site has 10+ content types, and loads of custom fields (field_x_revision + field_x_data tables!! for each field). I need to preserve those node ID's. I'm going to be doing this locally and the once I've got a completely merged database I'm going to put it back on the live site.

Are there any drupal modules that can export nodes and also import them (and preserve the old node id's)?

Comment: You tagget it node-export... can't [Node export](https://drupal.org/project/node_export) do it already?

Comment: The nid column is a serial/autonumber controlled by the DBMS, so short of recreating those nodes manually with the correct nids, there isn't really. You might want to have a look into the [UUID module](https://drupal.org/project/uuid), built to solve this sort of problem for the future

Comment: This is the achilles' heel of Drupal right now, and is planned to be solved in 8 (so I've heard), but there's not much to work around this besides node_export, and have two completely similar environments to work with.

Comment: What @inertialmedia said. Things are vastly better in Drupal 8 (I've seen it with me own eyes :P), but for now Drupal really falls down in the areas of content staging/config management. We just have to do the best we can until D8 is out...

Comment: What is the format of your nodes backup ?

Comment: I have very limited exposure to these kind of restoration tasks in MySQL but I did things like this before on MSSQL and that had an option of "Enable ID inserts". Is there no option like that in MySQL?

Comment: @bsfoo116 I have an *.sql format of the whole database.

Comment: I would suggest to load the SQL in a new database, and generate a new dump filtered for the deleted uid's. You will run these generated statements against your Drupal database. The trouble is you will have to do this against `node`, `field_data_x` and `field_revision_x` tables at least. It is tedious work, but that is the only option I know if you only have a SQL file backup.

Comment: @Beebee that's MySQL's default behaviour so no need to specify an option. The usual problem with this is that some of the nids you're restoring might now have been used by other, newer nodes. Plus there's all the meta and field data tables to take into account too. If you're lucky you'll be able to cherry pick the data you want to restore, without having to refactor ids. But it's still an arduous, manual task in my experience

Comment: thanks @hw. I just started doing this. It made me think however, are there any GOTCHA's with this method?

Comment: 200 nodes deleted, it's going to be a long friday. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If your backup contains the previously existing users, you could try to recreate your production site locally... Here are the steps I would follow (never tested though):

- install a local drupal site with your backup (files should be restored as well) in the production site, via VBO
- put your production site in maintenance mode
- target all the new / updated nodes since the incident
- export them via Node Export
- reimport them locally (the nids should be preserved thanks to NodeExport and UUID)
- reinstall your local db in production